# Does somebody know a module, which has a function that returns a kb/s downloadspeed?

Tags: perl, module, download-speed

Does somebody know a module, which has a function that returns ( for example for eth0 ) the download speed?

Comment: I have gigabit ethernet but my Internet connection is ADSL. The phrasing of your question suggests that (for my system) you are looking for 1000 Mbit/s, is that right?

Comment: Then the phrasing was not ok. I'm interested in the Internet connection.

Comment: There is no reliable way to measure that. Speeds will vary depending on where the other end point is, what other traffic is going over the network at the time, and so on.

Comment: Yet there are tools which are printing the (changing) download-speed. Of course it would suffice some round about value.

Comment: That would be an estimate of the speed of a particular transfer between two particular end points. Not a generic measure of link speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Employ a monitoring program: atop, iftop, ntop, dstat, icinga, munin, knemo, ksysguardd

Comment: It's to laborious with this tools to get the needed info in my script. And the script doesn't run with superuser privileges.

Comment: Not true. There's nothing laborious about `my ($recv, $send) = qx'dstat --net 1 1' =~ /(\d+\w*)\s+(\d+\w*)\s+\z/;`. It runs fine without super user priv.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.cnn.com/';
my $file = 'cnn.html';
my $start = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];
getstore($url, $file);
my $time = Time::HiRes::tv_interval($start);
my $size = -s $file;

printf "Speed: %d kbps\n", $size/$time/1000;
```

Comment: This doesn't account for latency, etc. Once you make a connection, things might go very quickly.